# Navigate to different stack - Can't perform update on unmounted component (no-op)

Tags: react-native

I'm using `react-native-navigation v3` and I'm trying to go from a screen in one stack to another screen in a different stack.

When I trigger `onDetailButtonPress` from the `LoggedInStack`, I'm able to open the `ReleaseDetail` screen but the bottomTabNavigator disappears and I get an error: `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.`

What is causing this issue here? I'm able to navigate from the `HomeStack` to the `LoggedInStack` but not the other way around.

HomeStack.js:

```js
    const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
        {
            Home: {
                screen: HomeScreen
            },
            Settings: {
                screen: SettingsScreen
            },
            ReleaseDetail: {
                screen: ReleaseInfoContainerScreen
            },
            SettingOnboard: {
                screen: OnboardStack
            }
        },
        {
            headerMode: 'none'
        }
    )
```

LoggedInStack.js:

```js
    onDetailButtonPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate(
              NavigationActions.navigate({
                routeName: 'HomeStackView',
                params: {},
                action: NavigationActions.navigate({
                  routeName: 'ReleaseDetail',
                  params: {
                    releaseId: selectedReleaseId
                  }
                })
              })
            )
    }}


export const LoggedInStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        TabNavigator: {
            screen: connectedLoggedInTabContainerView,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null
            }
        },
        FullScreenPlayer: {
            screen: PlayerScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null
            }
        },
    },
    {
        mode: 'modal',
        headerMode: 'none'
    }
)
```

Comment: Mostly the previous stack is being destroyed?

Comment: How can I not 'destroy' the previous stack? How come it's working when I go from HomeStack to LoggedInStack? Note: LoggedInStack have `mode: 'modal'` if that makes a difference?

Comment: Please add your bottom tab navigator code

Comment: @MohamadKh75 Added bottom tab navigator code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
onDetailButtonPress={() =>
  this.props.navigation.navigate('ReleaseDetail', { releaseId: selectedReleaseId })
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to navigate from one stack to another, not within the same stack.

Comment: I know, this is ok in v4, so please give it a try

Comment: I'm using v3 though

Comment: And the error is regarding react unmounted component, I'm getting the same error with your suggested answer